# How to disable a linux process based on value returned by the command execution in chef recipe

Tags: linux, chef-infra

Requirement: I need to disable a linux "process" after I check that its "enabled". I want to automate this using Chef recipe.

Below is the example:
When I execute the command: `/usr/bin/systemctl is-enabled xinetd | /usr/bin/awk '{print} END {if(NR==0) print "disabled" }'` if it returns `enabled`, then I want to `disable` the  `xinetd`.

I am looking for the conditional command on how to check the `xinetd` returns enabled and use this as conditional check for disabling the `xinetd` process. like the below:

```
service 'xinetd' do
<just before disabling this I need to run the command to see that its enabled..>
  action [:disable]
end
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: If I have run the chef code: ```service 'xinetd' do
  action [:disable]
end``` then it executes the disable action everytime. But I am looking for a conditional statement where in the status of the command: ```/usr/bin/systemctl is-enabled xinetd | /usr/bin/awk '{print} END {if(NR==0) print "disabled" }'``` I should store in a variable and only of this value is "enabled" then I need to "disable" the xinetd process. I am not sure how I can have a conditional like this. any samples or links to such code is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

for conditioal execution of chef resource, use [a guard](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#guards), such as:

```rb
service 'xinetd' do
  action :disable
  only_if '/usr/bin/systemctl is-enabled xinetd'
end
```